Zig - Appending values to an ArrayList inside while loop override all values to the last entry fractions
Using Zig, as a new to the language, trying to perform few simple actions on a file.
I have a function with the purpose of getting a path to a file and returning path to a sorted file.
The function get a path to a file after the file been cleaned from special character, and each line has a single word.
While running the code below, the Array List always end up full of fractions of the last word.
const std = @import("std");
const GPA = std.heap.GeneralPurposeAllocator;
const log = std.log;
const File = std.fs.File;

pub fn sortFile(file_path: []u8, buffer: []u8) ![]u8 {
    // creating general purpose allocator
    var general_purpose_allocator = GPA(.{}){};
    const gpa = general_purpose_allocator.allocator();
    // Getting the path fitting base on OS
    var encoded_path_buffer = gpa.alloc(u8, file_path.len) catch unreachable;
    const encoded_file_sub_path = try encodePathForOs(file_path, encoded_path_buffer);
    // Creating reader
    var file_read: File = try cwd().openFile(encoded_file_sub_path, .{});
    defer file_read.close();
    const file_reader = file_read.reader();
    gpa.free(encoded_new_file_sub_path);
    // ArrayList for the words
    var lines = std.ArrayList([]u8).init(gpa);
    // Looping line by line (word per line) and inserting
    while (try file_reader.readUntilDelimiterOrEof(buffer, '\n')) |line| {
        log.warn("line: {s}\n", .{line});
        lines.append(line) catch |err| {
            return err;
        };
        log.warn("lines: {s}\n", .{lines.items});
    }
    const items = lines.items;
    log.warn("items: {s}\n", .{items});

    /// rest of function non relevant - for it to be reproducable:
    defer lines.deinit();
    return file_path;
}

Util — Encode for OS function:
const builtin = @import("builtin");
const os_tag = builtin.os.tag;
const unicode = std.unicode;
const std = @import("std");

fn encodePathForOs(path: []u8, encoded_path_buffer: []u8) ![]u8 {
    if (os_tag == .windows) {
        var i: usize = 0;
        while (i < path.len) : (i += 1) {
            const codepoint = try unicode.utf8Decode(path[i .. i + 1]);
            _ = try unicode.wtf8Encode(codepoint, encoded_path_buffer[i..]);
        }
        return encoded_path_buffer;
    } else {
        return path;
    }
}

The input file:
hello
this
is
a
test
this
is
a
test
this
is
a
test
this
is
a
test

Logs of each line before appending, and the state of the ArrayList at each iteration:
line: hello
lines: { hello }

line: this
lines: { this
, this }

line: is
lines: { is
s
, is
s, is }

line: a
lines: { a
s
, a
s, a
, a }

line: test
lines: { test
, test, te, t, test }

line: this
lines: { this
, this, th, t, this, this }

line: is
lines: { is
s
, is
s, is, i, is
s, is
s, is }

line: a
lines: { a
s
, a
s, a
, a, a
s, a
s, a
, a }

line: test
lines: { test
, test, te, t, test, test, te, t, test }

line: this
lines: { this
, this, th, t, this, this, th, t, this, this }

line: is
lines: { is
s
, is
s, is, i, is
s, is
s, is, i, is
s, is
s, is }

line: a
lines: { a
s
, a
s, a
, a, a
s, a
s, a
, a, a
s, a
s, a
, a }

line: test
lines: { test
, test, te, t, test, test, te, t, test, test, te, t, test }

line: this
lines: { this
, this, th, t, this, this, th, t, this, this, th, t, this, this }

line: is
lines: { is
s
, is
s, is, i, is
s, is
s, is, i, is
s, is
s, is, i, is
s, is
s, is }

line: a
lines: { a
s
, a
s, a
, a, a
s, a
s, a
, a, a
s, a
s, a
, a, a
s, a
s, a
, a }

line: test
lines: { test
, test, te, t, test, test, te, t, test, test, te, t, test, test, te, t, test }

The ArrayList at the end:
items: { test , test, te, t, test, test, te, t, test, test, te, t, test, test, te, t, test }
Tried many of the tricks.
Suspected that the word enter as a pointer and not a value, so tried to clone.
Tried to increase ArrayList size before appending.
Tried to use insert instead of append with index, try to make each word a slice by its own and insert it.
And many more hours of debugging with success.
Looked for similar questions, of course, but not much on Zig around.
I would be very happy to solve it, and even more to understand what is going on here.
Thanks!

So apparently the issue is about copying memory — the line is the same buffer that get overrides again and again, so the entries are all pointers to the same location which get change with the loop.
To solve the issue, I used:
    while (try file_reader.readUntilDelimiterOrEof(buffer, '\n')) |line| {
        const new_line: []u8 = try gpa.alloc(u8, line.len);
        @memcpy(new_line, line);
        try lines.append(new_line);
    }

Which copy the line into another memory buffer.

You can also use gpa.dupe(u8, line) which is a helper to do alloc() and then memcpy()

Cool! Thanks! If you want to add it as a comment for a vote go for it

this leaks memory, no? you never de-alloc what gpa.alloc returns (same applies if you'd use gpa.dupe I think).

Didn't notice, it is. should defer. Any advice for detecting memory leaks without profiling manually?

@avifen you can use std.testing.allocator in tests to detect memory leaks: https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/std/#std.testing.allocator

You use in tests to detect on the tests, no? Its helping with detection in the code itself?
